# What's the typical size of a SaaS or Web2.0 DB?

Tags: database, statistics, size, estimation

I would be grateful if you can estimate (based on your experience/knowledge) the typical size of the main database of:

- A SaaS web site
- A Web2.0 web site

Of course this varies by application type, architecture & user-base, but any average estimation would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Whilst I'm working it out, let me know how long is a piece of string :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine any average figure is going to be useful. You're trying to derive a usage pattern (database size) via a front-end technology (web 2.0) and there's going to be *no* correlation at all.

It's more useful to describe the particular use-case you're interested in and then perhaps you may get something more meaningful. But even then it's strongly dependent on the implementations used.

Comment: I understand there probably isn't any correlation, however, any estimation of estimated scale/range would be very useful for me, as I currently have no data to work with at all.

I need it for planning a cloud-computing service, based on some clustering technology.